# JQuery not working with Node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js

I cant seem to get JQuery to work in node.js. I have installed it through the command line with: "npm install jquery" and I have referenced the library on the page which is in my local directory in case that might work. Nothing seems to make it accept JQuery notation. How can i make this work? 
[image]

Comment: Try a few things first. One is more the script to the bottom of the page. (In this case your document is not ready because it's not loaded. 

Also try this: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: The code seems fine. I would suggest to see if the jquery scripts are actually loaded. In chrome, open developer tools > Newtork tab - here you can see all the http traffic. Maybe your scripts are missing on server or the path to the scripts is not correct

Comment: `npm install jquery` isn't enough to make jquery available to the page. That's simply not how this works.

Comment: All the pages are loaded. I moved the scripts to the bottom of the page. JQuery no conflict throws an error now. I cant seem to find any good examples of people using JQuery with node.js.

Comment: @Kevin B Do you know how to properly reference JQuery so that this code will work?

Comment: @Some_Dude research how to serve static files

Comment: @Kevin B, Thanks!! I'm still new to node. I looked up static files, found a tutorial on expressJS, and used that framework and got my page working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by using expressJS from this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gnsO8-xJ8rs)  which allows you to serve static files. JQuery works fine in node when doing it this way.

Comment: The problem with 'crash courses' is that I'm already really good at crashing... note the video creator has updated his [tutorial for 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L72fhGm1tfE)

Answer (score 1):

You referenced it, but I believe in a wrong way.
You can read the docs at:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery
You try to reference it as it would be in the same directory that your .html file is in, but it isn't.
NPM packages are installed in a directory named node_modules, but even though it is there you shouldn't refer to it in that way.
As you can read in a documentation that I've linked above, you should use normal

Or when using babel:
import $ from "jquery";
or when webpack
var $ = require("jquery");
What I believe you want to do is serve a static file with node.js. For that you shoudn't install jquery, but just use cdn like in the other cases.

Answer (score -4):

stupid question but did you serve your jquery file with nodejs? if not your nodejs server have to serve your html page and all its dependencies (image, css style-sheet and javascript file).

if it is done then try to add an windows.onload > https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload to your script, it ensure that all your document is loaded before launching your script.

```
window.onload = function() {
  /* your stuff */
}
```

By the way it's my first answer on stackoverflow so be kind if I did a mistake.

Comment: This doesnt work, it just throws an error inside the function as soon as it sees a $ sign.

Comment: does your nodejs server serve your static files? if not take a look at this: https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/servers/how-to-serve-static-files/